# What is a "LoadingCache"?

Tags: caching, guava

Google offers a "[loading cache](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html)", which is described as following:

> A semi-persistent mapping from keys to values. Values are automatically loaded by the cache, and are stored in the cache until either evicted or manually invalidated.

Unfortunately, the description above isn't terribly clear. what does it mean to be "automatically loaded"?

I'm hoping it means: "If a requested key does not exist in the cache, it is then added to it automatically".

this is somewhat supported by this statement (from the get() function):

> "Returns the value associated with in this cache, first loading that
>   value if necessary."

but again, the "loading" aspect of the cache is explained with the word "loading". way to go, Google :[

Comment: It does what you think it does. But I'm wondering why this question exists at all. Why didn't you try it first? It's not like it's complicated to setup given the huge amount of examples you can find either on Guava's GitHub project or on the Internet. You would have seen first hand that it's doing exactly what you think it's doing. Note that the word "load" is explictly used on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)), that the [Guava documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) (not Javadoc, real doc) explains this is further details.

Comment: Second google result for `LoadingCache` links to [Guava wiki page "CachesExplained"](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) - please read it and follow up with any further concrete questions if you still don't understand it's purpose.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: I'm not a java programmer. trying this out isn't trivial for me. Also, the wiki article is nice, but the term load is mentioned there exactly twice and I can just as easily find the term 'put' in similar contexts (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/put ).

Comment: @Xaerxess: thanks for the link. I did see it before i posted. It, too, does not explain what loading is besides saying: "LoadingCache can be useful [..], due to its automatic cache loading". which (again) explains nothing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Guava's wiki documentation has a [full definition](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) of it: (emphasis is mine)

> A `LoadingCache` is a `Cache` built with an attached `CacheLoader`. Creating a `CacheLoader` is typically as easy as implementing the method `V load(K key) throws Exception`. So, for example, you could create a `LoadingCache` with the following code:
>
> [...]
>
> The canonical way to query a `LoadingCache` is with the method `get(K)`. **This will either return an already cached value, or else use the cache's `CacheLoader` to atomically load a new value into the cache.** Because `CacheLoader` might throw an `Exception`, `LoadingCache.get(K)` throws `ExecutionException`. If you have defined a `CacheLoader` that does not declare any checked exceptions then you can perform cache lookups using `getUnchecked(K)`; however care must be taken not to call `getUnchecked` on caches whose `CacheLoader`s declare checked exceptions.

The sentence emphasized explains all there is to explain: a value is either taken from the cache or loaded when `get(K)` is called.

---

In the comments you said you want more emphasis on what is *loading*. When *you* put things in the cache, you *put*. When you don't put things in the cache, but the cache will compute and put it itself, the cache *loads* it for you.

Comment: thanks for confirming my question! I still think that explaining an 'X cache' with 'it will atomically X' isn't terribly descriptive and leaves room for doubt (and hence the question).

Comment: Regarding "atomically", refer to Java's ["atomic" definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html): it's code that will be executed "as a single action", which is important in multithreaded applications.

Comment: thanks. Perhaps I should be clearrer:  the focus isn't on atomicity. Its about the 'loading' bit. but that's clear now.

Comment: When *you* put things in the cache, you *put*. When you don't put things in the cache, but the cache will compute and put it itself, the cache *loads* it for you.

Comment: Exactly the definition that is missing from the docs. thanks!

Comment: Okay, I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Is there any benifit in performance when using 'getUnchecked' instead of 'get'?

Comment: How does the cache know what to load if all you hand to it is the key? Does it not need a value to go along with the key? If not, what purpose does it serve to have just a key with a null value?

Comment: @Flaom it's a `LoadingCache`, and `LoadingCache`s can only be created after providing a `CacheLoader`, which represents a function returning (loading) a value based on the key. So basically, you don't put the value in the cache, but tell the cache how to load a value when a key is requested and the corresponding value must be loaded. You should really read the whole page linked in the answer.

Comment: To add to that, one of the key benefits of a loading cache is that you can offload data that doesn't fit the cache to a cheaper or slower storage option, like a disk, where it can be persistent.